# Converting a application user Player to a user Developer, where developer extends Player

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, identity

I have a class `Player` - extending `ApplicationUser` - and `Developer` - extending `Player` -. I want the users to be able to become developers whenever they wish, so I would have to somehow convert an object of the class `Player` to one of the class `Developer` at some point, but I'm confused about how to actually do this.

```
public class Player : ApplicationUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<Playing> Playing { get; set; }
}

public class Developer : Player
{
    public DateTime DateConverted { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Game> Games { get; set; }
}
```

I though that I could retrieve the object `Player`, remove it from the database, instantiate a object of the type `Developer`, copying all information and save it. It would be something like this:

```
public virtual async Task<Developer> Convert(Player player)
{
    var developer = new Developer
    {
        Id             = player.Id,
        DateBirth      = player.DateBirth,
        DateCreated    = player.DateCreated,
        DateUpdated    = player.DateUpdated,
        Email          = player.Email,
        EmailConfirmed = player.EmailConfirmed,
        UserName       = player.UserName
    };

    Db.Players.Remove(player);
    Db.Developers.Add(developer);
}
```

The problem is: when I delete the entry of the player, all relationships get lost with it.

Is there a better/easier way to do this? As far as I know, I would only have to change the `discriminator` field in the `ApplicationUser` table to "developer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I haven't been able to fix this properly, but the only workaround that I've found was to not separate `Player` and `Developer` into two classes, but instead to keep both classes' properties in `Player`. The difference would be given only by the property `DateCoverted`, that represents the date in which a given `Player` was converted to a `Developer`.

Something like this:

```
public class Player : ApplicationUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<Playing> Playing { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DateConverted { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Game> Games { get; set; }
}

public class PlayerService : Service<Player>
{
    public virtual async Task<Player> Convert(string id)
    {
        var developer = await Db.Players.FindAsync(id);
        developer.DateConverted = DateTime.Now;
        await Update(developer);
        return developer;
    }
}
```